# Data Table not instantiating with data when using .each method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am having an issue when I am adding data to my table using the `.each` method in jQuery, then instantiating a `DataTable` afterwords. When viewing the page the data will show in the table, without the filtering options of the data table.

I don't need to use the `.each()` method, if there is a better way to do this. It is just what made the most sense to me at the time.

[image: Webpage]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script src=" https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" >
    <script src="js/users.js"></script>
</head>

    <body>

        <table id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

                $('tbody').append($('<tr>', {id: "test"}));
                var $arr_length = users.length;
                for(i = 0; i <= $arr_length; i++) {
                        var $row = $('tr').get(i+1);

                        $.each(users[i], function(index, value) {
                            $($row).append("<td>" + value + "</td>");
                        });

                        $($row).after($('<tr>', {id: "test"}));

                };

                $('#table').DataTable();

        });

    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: if you want to add new row follow this:- https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()

Comment: I need to be able to populate a table with data from an array, then I need to instantiate a data table onto that pre-existing table.

Comment: why not pass the data to databable and let it take care of it?

Comment: I'm pretty new at using Datatables and I am not really aware of all of the methods in which i can pass data to it. Is there a method in which i can pass it the array and it will just dump the values into a table?

Comment: Can I see your data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your ***users*** variable, so I assume it's an array of objects (one for each table row).

A first error is: ID must be unique, instead you create table rows with the same id:

```
$($row).after($('<tr>', {id: "test"}));
```

Because you are using [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) it's useless the external for loop.

A solution to your question can be based on [data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/):

```js
$(function () {
    var users = [{"id": '1', 'firstname': 'firstname1', 'lastname': 'lastname1', 'email': 'email1', 'gender': 'male'},
        {'id': '2', 'firstname': 'firstname2', 'lastname': 'lastname2', 'email': 'email2', 'gender': 'male'},
        {'id': '3', 'firstname': 'firstname3', 'lastname': 'lastname3', 'email': 'email3', 'gender': 'female'}];

    $('#table').dataTable({
        data: users, 
        columns: [
            { data: 'id' },
            { data: 'firstname' },
            { data: 'lastname' },
            { data: 'email' },
            {data: 'gender'}
        ]});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

A fixed solution based on your code can be:

```js
$(function () {
    var users = [{'id': '1', 'firstname': 'firstname1', 'lastname': 'lastname1', 'email': 'email1', 'gender': 'male'},
        {'id': '2', 'firstname': 'firstname2', 'lastname': 'lastname2', 'email': 'email2', 'gender': 'male'},
        {'id': '3', 'firstname': 'firstname3', 'lastname': 'lastname3', 'email': 'email3', 'gender': 'female'}];
    $.each(users, function (index, value) {
        $('#table tbody').append($('<tr/>', {id: value.id}) /*  create first td */
                .append($("<td/>", {text: value.id})) /*  create second td */
                .append($("<td/>", {text: value.firstname}))/* ....  */
                .append($("<td/>", {text: value.lastname}))
                .append($("<td/>", {text: value.email}))
                .append($("<td/>", {text: value.gender})));
    });
    $('#table').dataTable();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank-you. The users array was a separate js file that just had an array with the values.